# How to use this specific Repo function with web socket actions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have put together a small web socket todo app based on reading on-line tutorials and the like. I have a working app that submits data to the database and retrieves data, all with web socket functionality. Phoenix uses a module named Repo to make it convenient to invoke database actions, one Repo function, specifically **Repo.update_all** does not work when I attempt to set it to broadcast changes. *I know what the problem is* and my problem is that *I don't understand pattern matching well enough to write the function properly*. I would like to know/see how to fix this. My code is below with more commentary.

```
defmodule App.TestBeds do
  @moduledoc """
  The TestBeds context.
  """

  import Ecto.Query, warn: false
  alias App.Repo

  alias App.TestBeds.TestBed

  @topic inspect(__MODULE__)

  def subscribe do
    Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe(App.PubSub, @topic)
  end

  defp broadcast_change({:ok, result}, event) do
    Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast(App.PubSub, @topic, {__MODULE__, event, result})

    {:ok, result}
  end



  @doc """
  Creates a test_bed.

  ## Examples

      iex> create_test_bed(%{field: value})
      {:ok, %TestBed{}}

      iex> create_test_bed(%{field: bad_value})
      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{}}

  """
  def create_test_bed(attrs \\ %{}) do
    %TestBed{}
    |> TestBed.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()
    |> broadcast_change([:testbed, :created])
  end

  @doc """
  Updates a test_bed.

  ## Examples

      iex> update_test_bed(test_bed, %{field: new_value})
      {:ok, %TestBed{}}

      iex> update_test_bed(test_bed, %{field: bad_value})
      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{}}

  """
  def update_test_bed(%TestBed{} = test_bed, attrs) do
    test_bed
    |> TestBed.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.update()
    |> broadcast_change([:testbed, :updated])
  end


# This function does not work (Wrong number of arguments)

  def reset_testbeds do
    Repo.update_all(TestBed, set: [status: "Available"])
    |> broadcast_change([:testbed, :reset])
  end


end
```

**Stripped down version of the LiveView I am calling the function from**

```
defmodule AppWeb.PageLive do

  use AppWeb, :live_view
  alias App.TestBeds
  alias App.StatusActions

  def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
    TestBeds.subscribe()
    {:ok, socket}
  end



  def handle_event("sandbox", params, socket) do

    TestBeds.reset_testbeds()


    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def render(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <body class="bg-blue_body">
      <form phx-click="sandbox">
        <button
          class="bg-pink-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full"
          name="sandbox"
        >
          CLICK ME
        </button>
      </form>

    </body>
    """
  end
end
```

I am trying to invoke **reset_testbeds** from a live view so that all testbeds update their status property to "Available". I tried invoking the function like this: `TestBeds.reset_testbeds()` As I mentioned at the top of the submission, the number of arguments does not match. I tried rewriting it different ways to no avail. **My mental model of pattern matching and functions isn't developed yet.**

For clarity the code below will change the data and update but it does not do it across browser tabs per the websocket functionality:

```
  def reset_testbeds do
    Repo.update_all(TestBed, set: [status: "Available"])
    |> broadcast_change([:testbed, :reset])
  end
```

This is the bulk of pub/sub code

```
  @topic inspect(__MODULE__)

  def subscribe do
    Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe(App.PubSub, @topic)
  end

  defp broadcast_change({:ok, result}, event) do
    Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast(App.PubSub, @topic, {__MODULE__, event, result})

    {:ok, result}
  end
```

My liveview handle info function is:

```
  def handle_info({TestBeds, [:testbed | _], _}, socket) do
    {:noreply, assign(socket, testbeds: TestBeds.list_testbeds())}
  end
```

**I get this error**

```
 (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in App.TestBeds.broadcast_change/2
    (app 0.1.0) lib/app/test_beds.ex:17: App.TestBeds.broadcast_change({4, nil}, [:testbed, :reset])
    (app 0.1.0) lib/app_web/live/page_live.ex:117: AppWeb.PageLive.handle_event/3
    (phoenix_live_view 0.18.16) lib/phoenix_live_view/channel.ex:396: anonymous fn/3 in Phoenix.LiveView.Channel.view_handle_event/3
    (telemetry 1.2.1) c:/Users/Bill/Desktop/app/deps/telemetry/src/telemetry.erl:321: :telemetry.span/3
    (phoenix_live_view 0.18.16) lib/phoenix_live_view/channel.ex:216: Phoenix.LiveView.Channel.handle_info/2
    (stdlib 4.0.1) gen_server.erl:1120: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib 4.0.1) gen_server.erl:1197: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
    (stdlib 4.0.1) proc_lib.erl:250: :proc_lib.wake_up/3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Repo.update_all/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update_all/3) returns a tuple `{non_neg_integer(), nil | [term()]}`, while you are trying to pass it to  the function having the only clause `broadcast_change({:ok, result}, event)`.

In `handle_info({TestBeds, [:testbed | _], _}, socket)` clause you discard this `result` whatever it is supposed to be, hence you might simply declare another clause of `broadcast_change/2` for this particular case. Just add this:

```elixir
defp broadcast_change({count, _}, [:testbed, :reset]) do
  Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast(
    App.PubSub, @topic, {__MODULE__, [:testbed, :reset], count})

  {:ok, count}
end
```